# Docker: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

A docker with apache, tomcat and elasticsearch images starts and runs without issue. But after restart with **docker-compose down/up**, the following error occurs:

```
    29-Nov-2018 16:43:22.063 INFO [elasticsearch[_client_][scheduler][T#1]] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1348)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1336)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1195)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1156)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext.preserveContext(ThreadContext.java:273)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor.wrapRunnable(EsThreadPoolExecutor.java:159)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor.execute(EsThreadPoolExecutor.java:89)
        at org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool$ThreadedRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:455)
        at org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool$LoggingRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:419)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any idea how to avoid this error? Thanks in advance.